# sql duplicate erro by using unique key

Tags: mysql

```
number   naam      orderNumber
1        Piet      1
2        Junhan    2
3        Smith     3
```

- primary key: `number`
- unique key: `orderNumber`

this table ik can represent in java

In java i want to update the value `3` in column `orderNumber` to `1`, but value `1` is already  represented and `orderNumber` is an unique key.
so how can i update  two values `1`and `3` at the same time

```
Connection connect = connection.getConnection();     
String query = "UPDATEtable SET oderNumber = 1 WHERE number = 3";
PreparedStatement statement =connect.prepareStatement(query);
statement.executeUpdate();
statement.close();
Connection connect = connection.getConnection();
Stringquery = "UPDATE table SET oderNumber = 3 WHERE number = 1";
PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(query); 
statement.executeUpdate();
statement.close();
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you will have to temporarily use a 3rd unused order number (or null if your design permits) as a swapping point.